# How do I create and label subcategories within a category using ReactEcharts?

Tags: reactjs, charts, bar-chart, echarts, multiple-axes

ReactEcharts.
How to create and label subcategories within a category like in the screenshot.
entrance 1-5 - data sources.
entered and exit - source metrics.

Example data:
[
{
name: 'entered',
value: 40,
time: 09:00,
source: 'entrance 1'
},
{
name: 'exit',
value: 60,
time: 09:00,
source: 'entrance 1'
},
...
]
[image]

P.S. Interested only in the creation of similar sub-categories in a category with a caption from below for the entire group.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what your use case is. If you have a series for each "main" category and want them colored according to sub categories you can use [visual map categories](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#visualMap-piecewise.categories):

```js
visualmap: {
    type: 'piecewise',
    dimension: 3,
    categories: ['entrance 1', 'entrance 2', 'entrance 3', 'entrance 4', 'entrance 5'],
}
```

If you have one series for each of your sub categories and strange axis labels (like in the given image) use multiple axis and [format](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.nameTextStyle.rich) your axis labels according to your needs.